# FlutterAppRequiredException: The current directory does not appear to be a Flutter application project. No fix worked so far

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I have set up everythin correctly however, when choosing the root it does not idnetify the project i will post the pubspec below:

```
name: random_app
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_nfc_kit: ^3.3.1
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  ndef: ^0.3.1
  convert: ^3.0.1
  logging: ^1.0.2
  js: ^0.6.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  sqflite: ^2.3.0
  http: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.0
  json_serializable: ^4.1.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: im.nfc.flutter_nfc_kit
        pluginClass: FlutterNfcKitPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: FlutterNfcKitPlugin
      web:
        pluginClass: FlutterNfcKitWeb
        fileName: flutter_nfc_kit_web.dart


  #
```

Does anyone know how i can make it recognize the project?

I have tried installing Flutterfire twice and  Firebase CLI setp by step. I also tried opening the project in andorid studio many times and this doesnt fix the issue